# Getting the url when opening the application particular Activity by clicking the SMS url

Tags: android

I am able to open the sub Activity through the intent filter by clicking in the SMS url, but I need to access the URL so, that the ID which come from other activity can be access through the url directly to that sub Activity. so, how it can be done... for further information please kindly ask any queries. Thank you for your concern.

Comment: are you trying to pass something say id between 2 activities

Comment: yes, instead of sending id in the url how it can send invisible...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it was a web url that was intercepted, for example "www.roflcopter.se/hai/2u", then the data can be extracted like this:

```
Intent intent = parent.getIntent();
String action = intent.getAction(); // for example Intent.ACTION_VIEW
String host = intent.getData().getHost();   // "www.roflcopter.se"
List<String> segments = intent.getData().getPathSegments(); // {"hai", "2u"}
```

The same syntax can be used for all types of intercept. See which of these methods that return the data you are interested in. :)

Comment: absolutely right, thank's for your respond... as I was able to fine the answer some time after posting these question...  but can you tell me that instead of sending the url eg. www.myurl.com/hai/you.. how hai and you can send invisible to the url...

Comment: Unfortunately Im not sure how to do that. It would be better to open up a new question for that. In the meantime, could you accept my answer?

Comment: anyway thank you.. by the way do u know that custom schema is click event can be perform in android 2.2 eg. myapps.com is acceptable in 2.2 for opening the new apps... response awaited...